# I have a data String with multiple JSON Objects, how can I store all JSON Objects from the String in an Array filled with objects?

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, object

For example if I had a string of 3 json objects:

{"id":"1","status":"SENT","sent_at":"2020-02-25T11:00:02+00:00"},{"id":"2","status":"SENT","sent_at":"2020-02-18T11:00:02+00:00"},{"id":"3","status":"SENT","sent_at":"2020-02-11T11:00:03+00:00"}

(above example is one long string)

How can I store all above information in an Array of individual json objects? I'm using Java!

Comment: Which language are you working with? The specific parser will determine how can you represent this. Otherwise, simply adding square brackets to the beginning and the end makes this a valid array of json objects.

Comment: oh sorry Java!!

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1:

Convert to valid json by wrapping in `[...]`, ie (formatted for readability only):

```
[
    {"id":"1","status":"SENT","sent_at":"2020-02-25T11:00:02+00:00"},
    {"id":"2","status":"SENT","sent_at":"2020-02-18T11:00:02+00:00"},
    {"id":"3","status":"SENT","sent_at":"2020-02-11T11:00:03+00:00"}
]
```

#### Step 2:

Parse using your favorite library, eg

```
List<Object> objects = new ObjectMapper().readValue(str, List.class);
```

If you deperately need an array (not recommended):

```
Object[] array = objects.toArray();
```